# ERROR 000732: Input Rasters: Dataset input_dem does not exist or is not supported

Tags: arcpy

Context : DEM Modification using shapefile.
Scenario: Change elevation values of the dem using a polygon shapefile. Update the elevation values within each polygon according to the values specified in the "***" column of the shapefile.
Input
Raster
Shapefile

Output
Modified Raster

What is the problem?

**Code**

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:\Spekter\Task 3"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

inFeatures = r"E:\Spekter\Task 3\ModifyDEM.shp"
valField = "NewVal"
outRaster = r"E:\Spekter\Task 3\Task 3.gdb\Raster"
assignmentType = "CELL_CENTER"
priorityField = "NONE"
cellSize = 0.31
arcpy.conversion.PolygonToRaster(inFeatures, valField, outRaster, assignmentType, priorityField, cellSize)
print("Frist Section Completed")

output_location = r"E:\Spekter\Task 3"
raster_name = "Raster_updated.tif"
coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference(25832)
pixel_type = "32_BIT_FLOAT"
cellsize = 0.31
number_of_bands = 1
mosaic_method = "LAST"
mosaic_colormap_mode = "FIRST"
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(outRaster, output_location, raster_name, coordinate_system,
                                   pixel_type, cellsize, number_of_bands, mosaic_method, mosaic_colormap_mode)
print("Second Section Completed")

output_location = r"E:\Spekter\Task 3"
DEM_name = "DEM_updated.tif"
input_dem = r"E:\Spekter\Task 3\DEM.tif"
input_rasters = ["input_dem", "raster_name"]
coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference(25832)
pixel_type = "32_BIT_FLOAT"
cellsize = 0.31
number_of_bands = 1
mosaic_method = "LAST"
mosaic_colormap_mode = "FIRST"
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(input_rasters, output_location, DEM_name, coordinate_system,
                                   pixel_type, cellsize, number_of_bands, mosaic_method, mosaic_colormap_mode)

print("Task Complete")
```

**Error Message**

```
Frist Section Completed
Second Section Completed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Spekter/Task 3/Task 3 Python Script.py", line 38, in <module>
    pixel_type, cellsize, number_of_bands, mosaic_method, mosaic_colormap_mode)
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 18591, in MosaicToNewRaster
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 18588, in MosaicToNewRaster
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.MosaicToNewRaster_management(*gp_fixargs((input_rasters, output_location, raster_dataset_name_with_extension, coordinate_system_for_the_raster, pixel_type, cellsize, number_of_bands, mosaic_method, mosaic_colormap_mode), True)))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 512, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Rasters: Dataset input_dem does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (MosaicToNewRaster).
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Kindly add some context to your code. Take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)for guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

`"input_dem"` is a literal string so ArcGIS looks for a raster called "input_dem" and it doesn't exist.  You defined the variables `input_dem` and `raster_name` earlier so to use those variables, change:

```
input_rasters = ["input_dem", "raster_name"]
```

To

```
input_rasters = [input_dem, raster_name]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: Glad it worked. Please upvote and/or accept https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers